# Why is there different number of elements in Spark DataFrames before and after writing to a new Cassandra table?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

In my code I read a data from an existing Cassandra table into a Spark DataFrame and transform it to build a set of new tables with the reverse mappings of the original data (the end goal is to serve the search queries that come via the REST API).

Recently I have added some tracing and discovered a thing I cannot explain.
Below is a piece of Scala code to illustrate the matter.

```scala
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
//
// control point 1: before writing the data to Cassandra
val inputCount = df.count
// write data to new C* table
df.createCassandraTable(keyspaceName, tableName, <otherArgs>)
df.write.mode("append").cassandraFormat(tableName, keyspaceName).save()

// read data back
val readbackDf = sqlContext.read.cassandraFormat(tableName, keyspaceName).load().cache
// control point 2: data written to C* table
val outputCount = readbackDf.count

// Produces different numbers
println(s"Input count = ${inputCount}; output count = ${outputCount}")
```

If I calculate `.count` of the dataframe before I write the data to the newly created table, it differs from the `.count` of the dataframe I get by reading back from this new table.

Therefore, I've got 2 questions:

1. Why do I observe different values for `inputCount` and `outputCount`?
2. If I use the wrong way to calculate `outputCount` in the code above, what would be the correct approach?

Comment: Is it live database? Are there ongoing writes to `df`?

Comment: @user6910411 No, processing is performed in batches, and ingesting of the original data is separated from the processing, including building the reverse mappings.

Comment: 1) If cassandra is clustered, Can you please check values by logging into individual machines? What is the read strategy ANY or LOCAL_QUORUM or anything else? 

2) Is inputCount < outputCount? Is this behaviour due to "append" mode?

Comment: @AnuragSharma as for 2), inputCount > outputCount always. If I try multple runs with the same data, `inputCount` is the same, while `outputCount` fluctuates between the runs. For your question 1), let me double check once I get an access to my work PC. I'll post an update here. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check that primary key is really unique in the output table? Please compare structure of input & output tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed related to Cassandra consistency settings.
Many thanks [Anurag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4353033/anurag-sharma) who pointed it out.

It turned out that in my testing environment I used defaults for both read- and write- strategies, which is `LOCAL_ONE`. So that easily explains the divergence.

I ended up setting them both to `LOCAL_QUORUM`:

```
spark.cassandra.input.consistency.level=LOCAL_QUORUM
spark.cassandra.output.consistency.level=LOCAL_QUORUM
```

Having said that, I'd like to point out that I also tried setting only reads to `LOCAL_QUORUM`

```
spark.cassandra.input.consistency.level=LOCAL_QUORUM
spark.cassandra.output.consistency.level=LOCAL_ONE
```

which *almost* nullified the divergence.

**Yet, I was still able to observe the small divergence with these settings *sometimes* (one in 3-4 runs) with some of my ETL jobs.**

While I don't see significant performance degradation with both reads/writes consistency set to `LOCAL_QUORUM`, so that the issue doesn't block me anymore, I'm still curious why setting only reads to `LOCAL_QUORUM` doesn't fully cure the problem.

Could anyone suggest "for-dummies" explanation of this?